# why isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively() method of AssertJ is failing on same value objects?

Tags: java, assertion, assertj

I am comparing the data after uploading the excel sheet via an API response.

while comparing it is giving this error:
`assertThat(holdings.get(2)).isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(listOfDataFromExcel.get(2));`

> -actual  : ,country=N/A,state=N/A,leadLender=N/A,ownershipType=N/A,sponsor=N/A,originalGlobal=0,totalTrancheSize=0,managersHolding=0,svoRatingName=N/A,gicsSector=N/A,gicsGroup=N/A,gicsIndustry=N/A,gicsSubindustry=N/A,aboutFields=,additionalProperties={}]>
>
> expected: ,country=N/A,state=N/A,leadLender=N/A,ownershipType=N/A,sponsor=N/A,originalGlobal=0,totalTrancheSize=0,managersHolding=0,svoRatingName=N/A,gicsSector=N/A,gicsGroup=N/A,gicsIndustry=N/A,gicsSubindustry=N/A,aboutFields=,additionalProperties={}]>

What is the difference between these two objects exactly?

**Note:** I can't perform ***assert on each field*** separately due to the increasing line of code or ambiguity. For other columns having the same values, it is working fine.

Any suggestion or way to debug this would be a great help.

Comment: Make sure that the objects have a proper `equals` implementation, even the referenced objects. If not, they won't match, regardless of what the `toString` tells you.

Comment: A way to debug this would precisely be to assert on each field separately until you find the one(s) that differ.

Comment: I do agree with both above comments, note that since AssertJ 3.12 there is a new way of performing recursive comparison https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison.

The new recursive allows you to ignore all or some of the overridden equals method that would be used otherwise, see https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison-ignoring-equals